# Master's theorem with f(n)=log n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

For master's theorem `T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)` I am using 3 cases:

1. If `a*f(n/b) = c*f(n)` for some constant `c > 1` then `T(n) = (n^log(b) a)`
2. If `a*f(n/b) = f(n)` then `T(n) = (f(n) log(b) n)`
3. If `a*f(n/b) = c*f(n)` for some constant `c < 1` then `T(n) = (f(n))`

But when `f(n) = log n` or `n*log n`, the value of `c` is dependent on value of n. How do I solve the recursive function using master's theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find these three cases from [the Wikipedia article on the Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) a bit more useful:

- Case 1: f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>), where c < log<sub>b</sub> a
- Case 2: f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup> log<sup>k</sup> n), where c = log<sub>b</sub> a
- Case 3: f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>), where c > log<sub>b</sub> a

Now there is no direct dependence on the choice of n anymore - all that matters is the long-term growth rate of f and how it relates to the constants a and b.  Without seeing more specifics of the particular recurrence you're trying to solve, I can't offer any more specific advice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So for a case where f(n) = log n and a!=b, it won't fit 2nd case as c and k would have to be 1, but it'll give the function n*log n. So how do I check where this function fits? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Note that log n is not Theta(n^c) for any constant c.  The only possible case that works here is the middle one, which might work if you had that a = b.  If a != b, then you cannot directly apply the Master theorem to solve the recurrence and will have to find an alternate approach.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to hear! Thank you so much!

Comment: But, how can I solve the function if f(n) = log(n)? I am confused

Comment: The master theorem can't always be applied.  If it doesn't work, you need to use a different approach.  What specific recurrence are you trying to solve?

Comment: T(n) = a T(n/b) + log n and I have a condition that a!=b. I am kind of stuck

Comment: You should post your specific question as another example and give specific values of a and b - without them, we can't really help out.

Answer (score 10):

Usually, f(n) must be polynomial for the master theorem to apply - it doesn't apply for all functions. However, there is a limited "fourth case" for the master theorem, which allows it to apply to polylogarithmic functions.

**If** f(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> log<sup>k</sup> n), **then** T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> log <sup>k+1</sup> n).

In other words, suppose you have T(n) = 2T (n/2) + n log n. f(n) isn't a polynomial, but f(n)=n log n, and k = 1. Therefore, T(n) = O(n log<sup>2</sup> n)

See this handout for more information: http://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/S06-235/files/MasterTheorem-HandoutNoNotes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When f(n)=log(n), the Master theorem is not applicable. You should use the more generalized theorem, [Akra–Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

In result, T(n)=O(n).

[source](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~tarau/teaching/cf1/Master%20theorem.pdf).

Another way to find a more specific proof of this result is looking for the proof of the computational complexity of the "Optimal Sorted Matrix Search" algorithm.

[image]