# Solving T (n) = √2*T(n/2) + log n using master theorem

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

The question is :

```
T(n) = √2*T(n/2) + log n
```

I'm not sure whether the master theorem works here, and kinda stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks more like the Akra-Bazzi theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method#The_formula with `k=1`, `h=0`, `g(n)=log n`, `a=(2)^{1/2}`, `b=1/2`. In that case, `p=1/2` and you need to evaluate the integral `\int_1^x log(u)/u^{3/2} du`. You can use integration by parts, or a symbolic integrator. Wolfram Alpha tells me the indefinite integral is `-2(log u + 2)/u^{1/2} + C`, so the definite integral is `4 - 2(log x + 2)/x^{1/2}`. Adding `1` and multiplying by `x^{1/2}`, we get `T(x) = \Theta(5x^{1/2} - 2 log x - 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) have only constrains on your `a` and `b` which holds for your case. The fact that `a` is irrational and you have `log(n)` as your `f(n)` has no relation to it.

So in your case your `c = log2(sqrt(2)) = 1/2`. Since `n^c` grows faster than your log(n), the complexity of the recursion is `O(sqrt(n))`.

**P.S.** solution of Danyal is wrong as the complexity is not nlogn and the solution of Edward Doolittle is correct, also it is an overkill in this simple case.

Answer (score 1):

As per master theorem, f(n) should be polynomial but here

```
f(n) = logn
```

which is not a polynomial so it can not be solved by master theorem as per rules. I read somewhere about the fourth case as well. I must mention that as well.

It is also discussed here: 
[Master's theorem with f(n)=log n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735576/masters-theorem-with-fn-log-n)

However, there is a limited "fourth case" for the master theorem, which allows it to apply to polylogarithmic functions.

If

```
 f(n) = O(nlogba logk n), then T(n) = O(nlogba log k+1 n).
```

In other words, suppose you have T(n) = 2T (n/2) + n log n. f(n) isn't a polynomial, but f(n)=n log n, and k = 1. Therefore, T(n) = O(n log2 n)

See this handout for more information: http://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/S06-235/files/MasterTheorem-HandoutNoNotes.pdf