# Recurrence: T(n)=T(n/2)+ log N

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence, induction

I am stuck on a recurrence question.

T(n)=T(n/2)+ log N

What I have right now is that:

T(N) = T(N/2) + log N

T(N/2) = T(N/4) + log(N/2)

...

T(N) = T(N/ 2^k) + sum[i=0 and k {log (N/2^i)}]

I am stuck on what to do next. Please give me some suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: log (N/2^i) = log N - i * log 2

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the [Master Theorem](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf) (or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)). For most recurrences it is applicable and provides the answer very fast.

It basically gives you three categories and then the answer falls out. Given a recurrence of the form T (n) = aT (n/b) + f (n) we look for a,b, and f(n). In your case we have a=1, b=2, f(n)=log n.

Therefore (you have to look at the referenced links) we fall into Case 2, where f(n) is in Theta(n^(log_b(a-eps)) log^k(n)) = Theta(n^0 log(n)), then the Master Theorem states that T(n) is in Theta(n^(log_b(a-eps)) log^(k+1)(n)) = Theta(log^2(n))

Answer (score 1):

```
 T(1) = c                         (= c + 0)
 T(2) = T(1) +  log(2)             = c + 1
 T(4) = T(2) +  log(4) = c + 1 + 2 = c + 3
 T(8) = T(4) +  log(8) = c + 3 + 3 = c + 6
T(16) = T(8) + log(16) = c + 6 + 4 = c + 10
...

n | T(n)  | T(n) - T(n-1)
--+---------------------
 1| c +  0| -
 2| c +  1| 1
 4| c +  3| 2
 8| c +  6| 3
16| c + 10| 4

T(n) = c + (log n)(1 + log n) / 2 = O(log^2 n)
```

Another way to see the same thing:

```
n = 2^m
S(m) = T(2^m) = T(2^m / 2) + log(2^m) = S(m - 1) + m
m | S(m)
--+-----
0 | c
1 | c + 1
2 | c + 1 + 2 = c + 3
3 | c + 3 + 3 = c + 6
4 | c + 6 + 4 = c + 10
...
S(m) = c + m(m + 1) / 2
T(2^m) = c + m(m + 1) / 2
T(n) = c + (log n)(1 + log n) / 2 = O(log^2 n)
```

Answer (score 0):

termination condition is not given in the mathematical equation so it is better if you solve this question with the help of modified version of master's theorem. I am providing here a link for these kind of problems, please have a look on this question probably you will get what you are looking for.
have a look on the second answer please.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735576/masters-theorem-with-fn-log-n)