# Master Theorem with function nlogn

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, master-theorem

We recently got tasks in my study to solve the complexity of recursive functions with the master theorem. I am aware that those questions have been asked a lot here, but I can't figure out the answer to this question from those.
One question, in particular, describes the problem well: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735576/masters-theorem-with-fn-log-n)

My problem is for the recursive function `T(n) = 5*T(n/3) + n *log(n)`.
As stated in the other question, this should be solvable with the second case (or the unofficial fourth case, those a pretty similar). 
However, I can't find a Big-Theta of `f(n) = nlogn with a =5 and b = 3`.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems to me you can apply case 1 (i.e. f(n) = O(n^c) where c < ccrit).

Comment: The definitions in that question (not its accepted answer) are dubious (they are all the exact same case). Use the definition from a more reputable source instead (e.g. Wikipedia).

Comment: (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-master-theorem-for-divide-and-conquer-recurrences/) This link will be helpful to you. It is an based on advanced version of master's theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved with the Master theorem if we can show that `f(n) = n log n = O(n^(log_3 5-\epsilon))`

if holds then the result follows from the first case of the Master Theorem

`T(n) = Θ(n^(log_3 5))`

To see that;

- take `lim (n log n)/n^(log_3 5))`
- [evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_3%205) log_3 5 ~ = 1.4649..
- substruct some epsilon = 0.0049...>0,
- `lim (n log n)/n^(1.46)`
- cancel n's
- `limit log n / n^(0.45) = 0` and take the first H'ospital
- `limit n^(0.54)/(n * 0.46) =0`